# Go for a swim, come out a new man

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is it an idiomatic sentence? If not, could you say please English natives version. Under what circuimstances we could use the expression?

> Go for a swim, come out a new man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reads as a *suggestion*, or a *recommendation*. It's telling you that you *should* go for a swim, *because* it will make you feel like a new man.

You see this kind of expression in advertisements, eg "visit Scotland, discover a new world", or "Feel like someone special, fly United" (I made these up).

Comment: 'Come out' may have a certain ambiguous quality for some people.